# Equivalence of two different versions of "change of basis matrix"?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a question regarding basis change and the matrix that represents it. I understand the concept, though I've noticed a different formula/proof in different math books and I don't understand how they're equivalent.

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space. Let $B$ and $C$ be two basis for $V$. Say we wanted to make a transition from $B$ to $C$.

- One formula I found states: $$M_{B\to C} = \begin{bmatrix}
      \vdots & \vdots & \dots  & \vdots \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \dots  & \vdots \\
      [c_1]_B & [c_2]_B & \dots  & [c_n]_B \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \dots  & \vdots
  \end{bmatrix}$$
- Where as a different formula (from Wikipedia) states: $$M_{B\to C} = \begin{bmatrix}
      \vdots & \vdots & \dots  & \vdots \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \dots  & \vdots \\
      [b_1]_C & [b_2]_C & \dots  & [b_n]_C \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \dots  & \vdots
  \end{bmatrix}$$

I don't understand how both formulas mean a basis transition from $B$ to $C$?

Comment: The second one is correct. Are you sure the previous one didn't switch the roles of bases $B$ and $C$?

Comment: I got the first formula from a document which belongs to a Linear Algebra course in the Technion: http://moodle.technion.ac.il/pluginfile.php/357562/mod_resource/content/0/Dapei_Ezer/basis_change.pdf

The document is in Hebrew, but the formula is clear. So it's wrong then?

Comment: I think so. One way to check is $M_{B\to C}e_i$ should give you matrix representation of $b_i$ with respect to $C$, the new basis. That is why we  call it a transition matrix from $B$ to $C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two things: vectors, and their coordinates in a basis. Some confusion arises because the set of $n$-tuples in a field (which is, essentially, a set of coordinates) is itself a vector space, where the coordinates of the vectors in the standard basis are the $n$-tuples themselves:

$(a_1,\dots,a_n) = a_1(1,0,\dots,0) + \cdots + a_n(0,0,\dots,1)$.

However, in general, the coordinates have no "intrinsic" meaning, they are just meaningful *relative to a basis*.

So here is how I keep it straight: suppose $B$ is an "unusual" basis for $F^n$ (for illustrative purposes, I will take $F = \Bbb R$, and $n = 3$). For example we might have $B = \{(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}$. Suppose further that $C$ is the "standard" basis for $F^n$, in this case:

$C = \{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$.

If we are given $[v]_B = (2,3,4)$, for example, what that *means* is that:

$v = 2(1,1,0) + 3(1,0,1) + 4(0,1,1)$.

Clearly, then $[v]_C = (2,2,0) + (3,0,3) + (0,4,4) = (5,6,7)$.

So if $M$ is our "transition matrix" $B \to C$, we ought to have $M([v]_B) = [v]_C$.

Now $(1,0,0)$ in $B$ means $(1,1,0)$ in $C$. The matrix that takes the $n$-tuple (written as a column array) $(1,0,0)$ to $(1,1,0)$ will have its first column be $[b_1]_C$, as you can verify by matrix multiplication, and similarly with the other basis vectors of $B$. So in this example, we would expect to find:

$M_{B \to C} = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$

and, indeed we see that:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\\4\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}5\\6\\7\end{bmatrix}$

Hopefully this will convince you the second formula is indeed the correct one.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation was very clear and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=\{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n\}$ (old basis) and $C=\{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n\}$ (new basis) be bases for $V$. Let $[v]_T$ denote the coordinate vector of $v$ with respect to basis $T$ for $V$.

The transition matrix $M_{B\to C}$ gives you how you need to modify the $[v]_B$ (coordinate vector of $v$ with respect to the old basis $B$) in order to get $[v]_C$.

To derive it, write $v=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n v_i b_i$, where $[v]_B=[v_1\ \cdots v_n]^T$. Then taking the coordinate vector with respect to $C$, we have $[v]_C=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^nv_i[b_i]_C$. But the right hand side is the matrix product $M_{B\to C}[v]_B$ where $M_{B\to C}=[[b_1]_C\ [b_2]_C\ \cdots [b_n]_C]$. In particular, if $e_i$ is the standard basis vector with $1$ on the $i^{th}$ position and $0$ otherwise, then $[b_i]_C=M_{B\to C}e_i$, which makes sense.